# How to setup this data to work with a view and a model

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am having issues not sure how I would set this up with model, view and controller. I am new to codigniter and a bit lost still learning. I set everything up in the controller which I know now it is wrong the page comes up with page cannot display when I insert a record after I hit submit. when it should just redirect me back to were I inserted the record.

employee controller

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Employee extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('employee_model');

    }   

    //Insert the employee 
        public function  insert_employee()
        { 


            $data=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'LanId'=>$this->input->post('LanId'),
                'reason'=>$this->input->post('reason'),
                'PepNumber'=>$this->input->post('PepNumber'),
                'Employee_Number'=>$this->input->post('Employee_Number'),
                'department'=>$this->input->post('department'),

                'status'=>1);
            //print_r($data);

            $result=$this->employee_model->insert_employee($data);
            if($result==true)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Employee Records Added Successfully");
                redirect('employee/index');

            }
            else
            {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"Employee Records Added Failed");
                redirect('employee/index');


            }
        }
```

employee model

```
<?php

class Employee_model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function insert_employee($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('employee_list',$data);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false:true;
    }
    public function get_employee()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('employee_list');
        $this->db->where('status',1);

        $query =$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    public function delete_employee($id,$data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('employee_list',$data);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false:true;
    }
    public function edit_employee($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('employee_list');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $query =$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
    public function update_employee($data,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('employee_list',$data);
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() != 1 ) ? false:true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you've already done that in the constructor or autoload, you have to load your model before using it : `$this->load->model("employee_model");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't load the model before using it.

There are multiple ways to work with models.

If you need it punctually, you can load it in your function :

```
public function myFunction()
{
    $this->load->model("mymodel");
    $this->mymodel->myfunction();
}
```

However if it is a very common model in your controller, you can load once for all in your constructor :

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mymodel');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->mymodel->myfunc();
    }
}
```

Finally, if it's a central model in your app, you can load it for all your controllers.

Go to application/config/autoload.php :

```
$autoload['model'] = array("mymodel");
```

EDIT : Also, the return on your model are not correct.

```
return $this->db->affected_rows(); //It's enought :)
```

Comment: this is all written in the controller is that incorrect

Comment: I don't see the `load->model()` in the code you provided.

Comment: I saw, but still, in the controller you need to load the model.

Comment: $data=array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'LanId'=>$this->input->post('LanId'),
                'reason'=>$this->input->post('reason'),
                'PepNumber'=>$this->input->post('PepNumber'),
                'Employee_Number'=>$this->input->post('Employee_Number'),
                'department'=>$this->input->post('department'),

                'status'=>1);
            //print_r($data);   I was wondering if this should be in the model

Comment: I keep geting page cannot display after entering the data

Comment: @Veronica, please read my answer and comments. You MUST load the model in your controller.

Comment: I tried loading the model still get page cannot display

Comment: Can you update your question with the new version of the function ? Also which url are you trying to access ?

Comment: after the data is entered suppose to go to $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Employee Records Added Successfully");
   redirect('employee/index');

Comment: redirect('employee/index')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71114/discussion-between-adrienxl-and-veronica).

Answer (score 0):

Working with models in codeigniter:

```
$this->load->model('Model_Name');
```

And the you call methods from Model_Name class:

```
$this->Model_Name->some_method($parametar1, $parametar2);
```